# search in users by cn in ou=users ,ou=system directory in ldap

Tags: java, ldap

i am trying to search user in users directory(ou=users,ou=system), but i am not getting result plz help me out.
following is my code for search users directory

```
    public void search(String uid) {
    String searchBase = "ou=users,ou=system";

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, rootpass);
    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {

![enter image description here][1]      // Create the initial directory context
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        // Create the search controls
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();

        // Specify the search scope
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] { "uid", "cn" });

        String searchFilter =" (uid="+uid+") ";//"(objectclass=*)"; //" (uid="+uid+") ";

        // initialize counter to total the results
        int totalResults = 0;

        // Search for objects using the filter
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter,
                searchCtls);

        while (answer.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();

            totalResults++;

            System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName());
            System.out.println(">>>");
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my directory structure

Comment: where is it ? the structure that is ... did you made sure that you have successfully logged in (are you logging anonymously ?)

Comment: Are you getting any error ? If no ,what is getting printed ?

Comment: Also try calling getAttributes() on SearchResults and see what all attributes are there.

Comment: nothing is printed.. but whent i search in any other directory it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [this sample](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/BasicJNDISearch).

Answer (score 1):

If "nothing is printed but when I search in any other directory it works fine", the possibilities boil down to:

- you are failing to connect to the LDAP directory at all
- your search base is wrong
- your filter is wrong
- the record you're searching for does not exist
- the credentials you're using to bind don't have permissions to search in that location

Some of those will throw a NamingException, but others (like "record does not exist" or "no permission to search") will simply return no results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the User folder goes, the answer is in another post  [LDAP Directory Entry in .Net - not working with OU=Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405011/ldap-directory-entry-in-net-not-working-with-ou-users)

> This may seem silly and stupid, but the default tree setup in Active Directory is **not OU=Users**,dc=domain,dc=com but rather **CN=Users**,dc=domain,dc=com (Note the CN= not the OU= for Users.