# LDAP search not finding entries in child OUs

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Say you have an LDAP with the following structure:

```
dc=corp,dc=com
|--dc=security
   |--ou=users
      |--ou=corporate
      |  |--ou=it
      |     |--it-user1
      |     |--it-user2
      |--user1
      |--user2
      |--user3
```

I need a search query that will look at all entries under the users ou, including those under corporate and it.

Currently I am trying the following:

```
uid=it-user2,ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com
```

The scope of the search is set as subtree. I was under the impression that the subtree scope would cause the LDAP to search recursively through the entire tree, but that does not seem to be the case. However, if I add the full path into the search as I have below, the entry is found.

```
uid=it-user2,ou=it,ou=corporate,ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com
```

Could someone give me an idea of where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your search context (i.e., the search base) to where your object/entry is stored. Based on your example, the search context is `ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com`. When you set the search scope to subtree, it should find the entry or entries that match your critera (i.e., search filter). For example,

```
ldapsearch -h SERVER -b ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com -s sub "(uid=it-user2)"
```

Of course, with the 'subtree' search scope, you could even set the search context to a higher level container (e.g., `dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com`). Your entry would still be found as long as it matches the criteria specified by your filter. Since you're searching for all entries under the `ou=users` container, your query would probably look like this:

```
ldapsearch -h SERVER -b ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com -s sub "(uid=*)"
```

or

```
ldapsearch -h SERVER -b ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com -s sub "(objectclass=*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fought this for hours - CN=Users  [LDAP Directory Entry in .Net - not working with OU=Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405011/ldap-directory-entry-in-net-not-working-with-ou-users)

> This may seem silly and stupid, but the default tree setup in Active Directory is **not OU=Users**,dc=domain,dc=com but rather **CN=Users**,dc=domain,dc=com (Note the CN= not the OU= for Users.)

Answer (score 0):

`uid=it-user2,ou=users,dc=security,dc=corp,dc=com` does not exist. The LDAP client must provide a base object to the search request which exists.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: The link to "LDAP: Search Best Practices" is broken.