# Try Catch Fail?

Tags: c#, wpf

Ive done some google and stuff and i cant seem to figure this out.
Try Catch just doesnt work the way i would expect it to.

here is the code.

```
  DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");
        foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
        {
            try {
                if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
                {
                    //you have access to the computer so yeah
                }
            }
            catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException err) {
                var ErrorMesage = err.Message;
                //Yeah you dont have access to this computer, lets write a subroutine to allow the user to put in a username and password to access it
            }
```

so when i run this i get a epic box popup and say something stupid like

{"The network path was not found.\r\n":null}

Comment: Sure that's a FileNotFoundException you're getting?

Comment: is your computer connected through Workgroup? And Make sure that WorkGroup Name is "WorkGroup"

Comment: Check your `DirectoryEntry` instance is created correctly - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405145/442444

Comment: Yes as i can see the computer name in node.name. the computer is on the same workgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
       DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");  **//Error occured here**
        foreach (DirectoryEntry Node in Discover.Children)
        {                
                if (Node.Properties.Count > 0)
                {
                    //you have access to the computer so yeah
                }
         }
    }
   catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException err) 
   {
                var ErrorMesage = err.Message;
                //Yeah you dont have access to this computer, lets write a subroutine to allow the user to put in a username and password to access it
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you are only attempt to check `Node.Properties.Count` access for errors, nothing more. Scope of the code `DirectoryEntry Discover = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://Workgroup");` has also to be put in `try` section.