# C#, LDAP: Trying to figure out DN, but RootDSE replies "invalid dn-syntax"

Tags: c#, exception, ldap

I'm currently trying to connect to a remote `LDAP-Server`. For that, I'm trying to figure out the domain with:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://141.83.80.30/lam/RootDSE");
```

Unfortunately, I'm confronted with the error:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'An invalid
>   dn-syntax was provided'

Comment: You need to provide the OU DN in format mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405011/ldap-directory-entry-in-net-not-working-with-ou-users)

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Ok, but since I'm trying to work with a remote ldap, I need to add the ip at the beginning right? With the format: 
`DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://141.83.80.30/ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com")`

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below snippet for remote LDAP connection.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com");
directoryEntry.Path = "LDAP://OU=Specific Users,OU=All Users,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the addition doesn't help. I'm using `LDAP://141.83.80.30/OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com` and it still explains, that the DN-Syntax is wrong

Comment: You have to change your query like above in example and replace `OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com` with your own OU details.

Comment: I found the solution: Basically @MuhammadHannan's solution is correct, but updating `directoryEntry.Path` overwrites the former path. Thus, one needs to set the path to `LDAP://example.com/OU=specific users,OU=all Users,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com`