# I am writing c# code wherein I want search for the details of a specific user from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

[image]I got a very useful code:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "redmond.corp.microsoft.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But the issue is that it lists down all the user of a domain, and I want to search the details based on the user specified logon name.

I tried a lot to modify the code as per my need, but I always get a reference exception.

Comment: you are no checking for the current user I can post you a simple example that you can follow as an example do a google search on the following method `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`

Comment: if you can modify the above code it will be helpful

Comment: I do not have access to my AD currently so I will post a simple example of what you can try.. what is the username you are trying to get.. are you getting it by there `domain\username` or  do they just type in their domain username

Comment: the username is like: alias@microsoft.com

Comment: so you need to split the alias from the domain also you can try the code that I post below to get your basics passing in your domain name give me a sec

Comment: okay sure...thanks for your quick response

Comment: Also on Stackoverflow there are tons of excellent working examples as well if you need even more in depth examples Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)) //pass in your domain as the second param if needed as well 
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,"yourusernamehere"))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```

look at all the property's of the `user`object when inspecting in the Debugger / QuickWatch and you can see email address etc...

Comment: unfortunately! this didn't worked for me....it's not throwing any exception but doesn't retrieve the value as expected.

Comment: your code makes complete sense but my situation is a little bit confusing, i have users located under the OU= user accounts under the domain : redmond.corp.microsoft.com so while using the above code do i not need to mention any container or ou details or the principal conext will server the purpose?

Comment: there are other bits of code that you can also use by creating your own class in regards to how AD works using some LDAP constructs as well as some little AD code like you are doing in your code.. you would use both PrincipalContext and create some other custom code that can get you all of what you need.. there are some awesome examples on Stackoverflow in regards to using AD I will try to dig up some examples that I currently use to display the example

Comment: Thanks a lot! please try to post some more examples here....i digged deep today to find some more examples...but I am not able to filter out the user from the domain...

Comment: what do you mean when you say you are not able to filter out the users from the domain..?

Comment: i mean we have a domain redmond.corp.microsoft.com which I am passing under contextType.domain and want search for a specific user by logon name as: alias@microsoft.com and display the fields of this user. The issue here is that every time i am attempting to search for a specific user(also tried with your example) i don't get the desired result.

Comment: Moreover, my users are are located under the OU=AccountUsers so i don'T UNDERSTAND if my code is searching under this ou fora user or not

Comment: you need to construct the `searcher.Filter` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825237/how-can-you-find-a-user-in-active-directory-from-c or do a google search on the following I do not have my working code on this machine `C# Stackoverflow ActiveDirectory Searcher.Filter`

Comment: I have added a snip from my AD to let you know my situation better....I will follow what you said but can you please help me understand this: as my need is to search for a user in the entire directory, by looking at the snip above can you comment on the connection string that i should use, like what domain name shall I mention(snip above)...